# need a regular expression to get width and height from image url in php

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

My image class

$temp=`<img class="alignnone  wp-image-6" alt="2166105529_70dd50ef4b_n" src="http://192.168.1.12/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/2166105529_70dd50ef4b_n-300x175.jpg" width="180" height="105">`

I want to grab width and height from the url i.e. `width="180"` and `height="105"`

I had already got the src part of that using

`preg_replace('/<img\s.*?\bsrc="(.*?)".*?>/si', $temp, $matches);`

$matches= it contains extracted src like this

```
http://192.168.1.12/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/2166105529_70dd50ef4b_n-300x175.jpg
```

Now how to extract width and height using regex or any other method also accepted??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the dom class in php is a better way. Much easier to use.
Example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c6d89fc6e0803ac38a3bc1ea9c61e081c1b71f08

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<img class="alignnone wp-image-6" alt="2166105529_70dd50ef4b_n" src="http://192.168.1.12/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/2166105529_70dd50ef4b_n-300x175.jpg" width="180" height="105">');

$img = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

$src= $img->item(0)->getAttribute('src'); 
$width= $img->item(0)->getAttribute('width'); 
$height= $img->item(0)->getAttribute('height'); 

echo $src ."<br/>";
echo $width."<br/>";;
echo $height."<br/>";;
```

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to use PHP's [DOM](http://php.net/dom) extension for this, because it's more reliable and knows how to parse HTML correctly, and knows something about character sets.

```
<?php

$temp='<img class="alignnone wp-image-6" alt="2166105529_70dd50ef4b_n" src="http://192.168.1.12/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/2166105529_70dd50ef4b_n-300x175.jpg" width="180" height="105">';

$dom = new \DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($temp);

$img = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0);

// Note: Values are returned as strings, not as numbers
$src = $img->getAttribute('src');
preg_match('/(.+)-([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)\.jpg$/', $src, $matches);

$width = $matches[2];
$height = $matches[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
list($height, $width) = explode("x",substr(strrchr( $url , "-" ),1,-4));
```

And if I misunderstood and you need to get it from the attributes, not the actual url of the image, then

```
$url= '<img class="alignnone wp-image-6" alt="2166105529_70dd50ef4b_n" src="http://192.168.1.12/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/2166105529_70dd50ef4b_n-300x175.jpg" width="180" height="105">';

echo substr(strstr( $url , "width" ),0,-1);
```

Will echo

```
width="180" height="105"
```